# Query performance using CTE

Tags: sql-server-2012, common-table-expression, query-hints

I am going to use hint OPTION (RECOMPILE) or OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN) at the end of query in my sp.Query contains union all operator so shall i use cte?will it improve or affect the performance?.suggest please.

```
Example

;with cte
{
QUERY 1
UNION ALL
QUERY 2
}

select * from cte OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: You have to compare query plans and  measure execution time on your data - it is impossible to give any generic hints here. What about CTE - I can't see any reason to use CTE here, you can simply use union query.

Comment: Cte is used here for using the hint OPTION (RECOMPILE) at the end of query.so cte is used here.